# Can we use XML format translations file instead JSON in React native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-i18next

Am developing react native application using react i18next lib, for translations i have used xml format in android for native, in react native can we use xml format translations file instead of JSON format.Is there any advantage of using JSON format?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're stuck on? Please include relevant code and error messages.

Comment: No am not facing any problem, i just wanted to check whether  can we use xml format

Answer (score 1):

i18next requires JSON format (or at least something that can be mapped to it).
https://www.i18next.com/misc/json-format

- If you're looking for something that converts XLIFF (XML) to JSON you may have a look at: https://github.com/locize/xliff
- If you're looking for something that converts Android String Resource (XML) to JSON you may have a look at: https://github.com/locize/android-string-resource

Additionally/Alternatively, i18next also accepts different i18n formats: https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils#i18n-formats

Comment: You could also manage your translations with a translation management system like https://docs.locize.com/integration/supported-formats This way you could download the translations in your desired format: https://github.com/locize/locize-cli#download-current-published-files